# Javascript/HTML onclick passing new value to running content slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

SLIDER CODE
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/03/15/parallax-content-slider-with-css3-and-jquery/

IMAGE MOCK:

[image]

I'd like to preface this by saying I'm not a dev, I'm a designer and know next to nothing about JavaScript.  On top of that, it's been about ten years since I've done any web work.  I've got a slider-based site I'm cobbling together and I'd like to add or modify some functionality to the slider.  The slider is invoked at the end the HTML file with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        
            $('#da-slider').cslider();
        
        });
    </script>
```

I'd like to add text buttons, as seen in the picture, that will change the page of the slider.  The slider generates buttons that are  but do not contain text as I would like.  Currently I have the text buttons as anchors with for example

```
<a href="#" onClick="$('#da-slider').cslider({current:2});"><p>Live PA</p></a>
```

but it creates a new slider at that page instead of changing the one that is already running.  Is there a way to pass this value to the one that is already running?  Is this a problem of scope?  Am I just using the wrong syntax to pass to an existing instance?  I tried looking for the code associated with the button spans but all I can find is the spot where they're created, but not how the clicks are handled.  I think it's using jQuery which I'm not familiar with.  Note the slider is jQuery-based, so that's loaded as well.

Comment: you created a new slider by clicking the anchor tag. what you want to do by clicking the anchor tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call is initializing a new cslider instance.

Looking at the source code they have a method page for changing the current page. Using the usual notation for jQuery you can change the page to the second page by doing:

```
    $('#da-slider').cslider('page', 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I knew I had to be calling it incorrectly.  I tried your suggestion in the form of    <a href="#" onClick="$('#da-slider').cslider('page', 2);"><p>Live PA</p></a>  and it displays but does not function.

Comment: Could you clarify "and it displays but does not function."

Comment: Sorry for being vague.  The text in the anchor displays but does not change the active page of the slider.  The arrows and buttons created by the js function properly.  I'm wondering if it's a global/local scope issue?  Or maybe that I need to call an update to the instance?  Normally I would just look at the button code and figure it out from that but it's handled by jQuery and I'm having a hard time interpreting it.  I can post the html and css on dropbox or pastebin if needed.  Thanks again.

Comment: It would be helpful yes, since the code you copied worked in my test so the problem must lie elsewhere @JamesH.

Comment: The cslider you are using on the page is older than the one referenced in your question. The old code doesn't have the page method. Just update the cslider (scripts/jquery.cslider.js file) and it will work @JamesH.

Comment: Where would I find that?  I've searched before and all I seem to get is that page and a wordpress plugin.  Thanks again!

Comment: So it looks like it IS the wordpress plugin, it also works with static html.  I just installed the 0.7 version and it is still not working.  Sorry this is such a chore.

Comment: The link you provided in the question has Download Source button, which downloads a zip file containing examples and javascript files. Download it and then copy the js/jquery.cslider.js file to the necessary folder.

As to where the folder is if you have wordpress site and it is a plugin then I'm guessing you can find it in a folder under wp-content/plugins/{plugin name} @JamesH.

Comment: As a remark the older cslider version does not provide a method to change the page manually. @JamesH.

Comment: So I replaced the 0.7 version with the one included in the newest archive and it worked!  Thanks, guess I needed someone with a fresh download haha.  Thanks so much for your time!